# How can I call an overloaded .NET function which uses a C# out argument from Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, reference, overloading

I know that Powershell can call .NET code, which might look like this

```
PS> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(($ScriptDir + ".\SharpSvn-x64\SharpSvn.dll"))
PS> $SvnClient = New-Object SharpSvn.SvnClient
```

And I know that where C# has `out` arguments, Powershell has `[ref]` arguments, which might look like this:

```
PS> $info = $null
PS> $SvnClient.GetInfo($repo.local, ([ref]$info))

True

PS> $info

(...long output snipped...)
NodeKind           : Directory
Revision           : 16298
Uri                : http://server/path/to/remoterepo
FullPath           : C:\path\to\localrepo
(...long output snipped...)
```

And I know that in C# you can overload functions, like the SharpSvn library does for its [SvnClient.Update() method](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/Overload_SharpSvn_SvnClient_Update.htm):

1. `Update(ICollection(String))` - Recursively updates the specified paths to the latest (HEAD) revision
2. `Update(String)` - Recursively updates the specified path to the latest (HEAD) revision
3. `Update(ICollection(String), SvnUpdateArgs)` - Updates the specified paths to the specified revision
4. `Update(ICollection(String), SvnUpdateResult)` - Recursively updates the specified paths to the latest (HEAD) revision
5. `Update(String, SvnUpdateArgs)` - Recursively updates the specified path
6. `Update(String, SvnUpdateResult)` - Recursively updates the specified path to the latest (HEAD) revision
7. `Update(ICollection(String), SvnUpdateArgs, SvnUpdateResult)` - Updates the specified paths to the specified revision
8. `Update(String, SvnUpdateArgs, SvnUpdateResult)` - Recursively updates the specified path to the latest (HEAD) revision

But, what if we want to put all of this together? If, say, I want to call the 6th version of `Update()`, the one that takes a String and an SvnUpdateResult, where the SvnUpdateResult is a C# out object? My first instinct was to try something like this:

```
PS> $repopath = "C:\path\to\localrepo"
PS> $update = $null
PS> $svnclient.update($repopath, [ref]$update)

Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Update" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:18
+ $svnclient.update <<<< ($repopath, [ref]$update)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

OK, maybe I have to cast the arguments?

```
PS> $svnclient.update([string]$repopath, [ref][SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult]$update)

Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Update" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:18
+ $svnclient.update <<<< ([string]$repopath, [ref][SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult]$update)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. Other things I've tried:

- casting `$update` as `[SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult][ref]` - that is, reversing the order that I cast it. That results in an error which states: "[ref] can only be the final type in type conversion sequence."
- Casting `$update` to `SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult` before using it: `$update = [SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult]$null`. This results in the same "Multiple ambiguous overloads" error I ran into above
- Casting `$update` to `ref` before using it: `$update = [ref]$null`. This results in an error: 'Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.PSReference" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSReference" to type "SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult".'

It seems like casting it twice is the problem - the final cast just overrides the first cast, they don't complement each other. Is this what's happening? Is there a way to cast something twice? Is there another way around this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've found that you can examine the overloaded definitions with `$svnclient.Update.OverloadedDefinitions`, but there's no way to call them from there that I can see.

Comment: One way to get some insight into PowerShell's type conversion/member resolution inner works is to run `Trace-Command -Name All -Expression {$svnclient.update($repopath, [ref]$update)} -PSHost` and see if that reveals anything useful.

Comment: That returns the same "Multiple ambiguous overloads" message, unfortunately.

Comment: I created a simple repro for this issue and [filed an issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2936) for PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an ideal solution but you could use Add-Type and make a more PowerShell friendly type that wraps the Update method.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition "
public class SvnClientEx
{
   public static SvnUpdateResult Update(SvnClient client, string path)
   {
       SvnUpdateResult result; 
       client.Update(path, out result);
       return result; 
   } 
}
"

$result = [SvnClient]::Update($svnClient, $repopath)
```

Comment: That results in an error like this: `Add-Type : c:\Users\autotester\AppData\Local\Temp\89jqcyvc.0.cs(4) : The type or namespace name 'SvnClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`... I've tried adding a `using SharpSvn;` at the top of the definition, but it gives a similar error about not being able to find SharpSvn. I'm sure I'm missing something simple... I'm not very familiar with C# in general or how Powershell interacts with it in particular. What am I doing wrong? (And thanks for the pointer!)

Comment: Take a look at Add-Type's ReferencedAssemblies parameter. You'll need to add the SVN client assembly to the Add-Type command above. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

This does seem to be quite hard to get right.

What version of PowerShell is this?
Are `SvnUpdateArgs` and `SvnUpdateResult` related (i.e. one class derives from the other)? I shall assume not.

Based on a similar scenario I constructed, with the current version (4.0) of PowerShell, this works, I think:

```
PS> $repopath = "C:\path\to\localrepo"
PS> [SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult]$update = $null
PS> $svnclient.Update([string]$repopath, [ref]$update)
```

**However, I could only get this to work with one of the overloads!?** Not sure if it is by coincidence, but this was the overload which was listed first when I said `$svnclient.Update` to see the overload definitions.

In my version of PowerShell, if I give the second argument as `[ref][SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult]$update`, the overload seems to be resolved correctly, the method runs without error, but the object assigned to the "out" parameter seems to be lost.

Even if `$repopath` is declared type-safely as `[string]$repopath = "C:\path\to\localrepo"`, it seems that we still have to say `[string]$repopath` again when we pass it (by value).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue in PowerShell when there is a Method that you call with an out parameter of a class and another overload with a similar signature (the class can be any class in this signature.)

I created a simple repro for this issue and [filed an issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2936) for PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a code block and access the result (out) object within this block:

```
PS> $repopath = "C:\path\to\localrepo"
PS> $svnclient.update($repopath, { 
      Write-Host $_.Revision
      Write-Host $_.HasRevision
      # Access all the Member and Methods of the result object here
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could do:

First, the result returned by `$svnclient.update` is a `PSMethod`. `PSMethod` has an `Invoke` method. You could try using it.

Second, if that doesn't work you could use real reflection:

```
# To get all methods:
$svnclient.gettype().getmethods()     

# Then filter the results to get overload you need.
# Use GetParameters to get parameters of an overloaded method 
# return by GetMethods
# For example (using PS 3.0 features):

$svnclient.gettype().getmethods()|? name -eq Update |
% {write-host "***`n"';$_} | % GetParameters

# Will list parameter sets for each overload of Update, each set separated by stars

# Alternatively use getmethod with appropriate parameters    
# GetMethod (link below) can be used to select correct overload without the 
# filtering above. The next to the last overload of GetMethod at the link is the one to use

# After obtaining correct overload, then call the Invoke method like this:
$correctOverload.Invoke( $svnclient, @($repopath, [ref] $SvnUpdateResult))
```

[GetMethod Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @micah-r-ledbetter Either writing C# CmdLets or this reflection solution seems like the best option.  I'll follow-up with the PowerShell team about why the call isn't working, but I doubt the fix will be in PowerShell soon.  

I found problems in the above solution (the invoke syntax is wrong.)  If you are interested in the fixes to make the above work, reply back.